# SSAS - Issue with SQL Server Data Source

Tags: sql-server

I am working on SSAS Tabular model and have an SQL Server data source (Provider=SQLNCLI11) to which it connects and processes data successfully. However, since a few weeks, the data source connection interface for SQL Server has changed. Now, when creating a new data source, I am able to connect and preview the data, but when processing the table, I encounter the error: "Could not validate credentials. See output window for details." No further details can be found in the output window.

Has anyone else encountered this issue? Your assistance would be greatly appreciated.